# Django NameError while using Q object

Tags: django

I using Q object as for search,

```
tracks_list = Track.objects.order_by("rating")
query = request.GET.get("search")

if query:
    tracks_list = tracks_list.filter(
            Q(title__icontains(query))|
            Q(genres__name__icontains(query))
    ).distinct()
```

and my models are described as,

```
class Track(models.Model):

  title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
  genres = SortedManyToManyField(Genre)
  rating = models.IntegerField(default=0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(10), MinValueValidator(0)])

class Genre(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True, null='False')
  views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
```

Yet I am receiving a NameError stating `global name 'title__icontains' is not defined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need

```
title__icontains=query
```

instead of

```
title__icontains(query)
```

the same applies for `genres__name__icontains`